# Another "Accuracy metric values are missing" in caret::train, this time using polr

Tags: r, modeling, r-caret

I'm trying to use the `polr` method in `caret::train` and am getting the `Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:` error. I've gone through many, many of the other questions covering this error and either they don't apply or the answers don't work.

Unfortunately, my data is proprietary so I can't provide it and I have not been able to replicate this exact error in R's sample datasets.

1. I prep the model using `recipes`, did I do something wrong?
2. Some of my factor predictors are unbalanced, could that be part of it?
3. Is anything in my code weird?
4. What else could be going on?

Anyway, here is what I'm working with. There are no `NA`s in my dataset:

```
str(dataset)
 $ outcome      : Factor w/ 3 levels "Low","Medium",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 1 ...
 $ numericvar1  : num  451424 40505 189327 8760 12979 ...
 $ numericvar2  : int  7 2 3 1 4 4 16 6 537 3 ...
 $ numericvar3  : int  4 1 1 1 1 1 2 4 116 3 ...
 $ numericvar4  : num  10 1 1 1 6 1 2 4 119 3 ...
 $ numericvar5  : num  15 50 50 2 2 ...
 $ numericvar6  : num  29.5 50 50 2 12 ...
 $ factor1      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ factor2      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ factor3      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ factor4      : Factor w/ 5 levels "level1","level2",..: 2 2 2 2 2 5 2 1 5 2 ...
 $ factor5      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ factor6      : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 ...

######################

rcp <- recipe(outcome ~ ., data = dataset) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_scale(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_center(all_numeric()) %>%
  prep()

dataset_bake <- bake(rcp, dataset)

str(dataset_bake)
 $ outcome          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Low","Medium",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 1 ...
 $ numericvar1      : num  0.3759 -0.071 0.0909 -0.1055 -0.1009 ...
 $ numericvar2      : num  -0.0671 -0.1051 -0.0975 -0.1126 -0.0899 ...
 $ numericvar3      : num  0.509 -0.318 -0.318 -0.318 -0.318 ...
 $ numericvar4      : num  0.16209 -0.20511 -0.20511 -0.20511 -0.00111 ...
 $ numericvar5      : num  0.1422 0.7318 0.7318 -0.0768 -0.0768 ...
 $ numericvar6      : num  0.0827 0.201 0.201 -0.076 -0.0183 ...
 $ factor1_No       : num  -2.095 0.477 -2.095 0.477 0.477 ...
 $ factor2_No       : num  0.199 0.199 0.199 0.199 0.199 ...
 $ factor3_No       : num  0.115 0.115 0.115 0.115 0.115 ...
 $ factor4_level2   : num  0.781 0.781 0.781 0.781 0.781 ...
 $ factor4_level3   : num  -0.236 -0.236 -0.236 -0.236 -0.236 ...
 $ factor4_level4   : num  -0.219 -0.219 -0.219 -0.219 -0.219 ...
 $ factor4_level5   : num  -0.206 -0.206 -0.206 -0.206 -0.206 ...
 $ factor5_No       : num  -0.697 -0.697 -0.697 -0.697 1.435 ...
 $ factor6_No       : num  0.206 0.206 0.206 0.206 0.206 ...

#################

bake_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          number = 10,
                          repeats = 3,
                          summaryFunction = multiClassSummary)


amodl <- train(outcome ~ .,
               data = dataset_bake,
               method = "polr",
               trControl = bake_ctrl,
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(method = "probit"))

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa        Mean_F1    Mean_Sensitivity Mean_Specificity Mean_Pos_Pred_Value
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA      Min.   : NA      Min.   : NA        
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA      1st Qu.: NA      1st Qu.: NA        
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA      Median : NA      Median : NA        
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN      Mean   :NaN      Mean   :NaN        
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA      3rd Qu.: NA      3rd Qu.: NA        
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA      Max.   : NA      Max.   : NA        
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1     NA's   :1     NA's   :1        NA's   :1        NA's   :1          
 Mean_Neg_Pred_Value Mean_Precision  Mean_Recall  Mean_Detection_Rate Mean_Balanced_Accuracy
 Min.   : NA         Min.   : NA    Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA         Min.   : NA           
 1st Qu.: NA         1st Qu.: NA    1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA         1st Qu.: NA           
 Median : NA         Median : NA    Median : NA   Median : NA         Median : NA           
 Mean   :NaN         Mean   :NaN    Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN         Mean   :NaN           
 3rd Qu.: NA         3rd Qu.: NA    3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA         3rd Qu.: NA           
 Max.   : NA         Max.   : NA    Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA         Max.   : NA           
 NA's   :1           NA's   :1      NA's   :1     NA's   :1           NA's   :1
```

Variables with unbalanced values:

```
factor2: 3.8% Yes
factor3: 1.3% Yes
factor4:
    level1: 24%
    level2: 62%
    level3: 5%
    level4: 5%
    level5: 4%
factor6: 4.0% Yes
```

I really do not want to eliminate the unbalanced variables because when they are "Yes" they almost certainly affect the outcome.

I've tried using `MASS::polr` directly but am running into issues there as well. Maybe the error offers info on why it's not working in `train`:

```
polr_mod <- polr(outcome ~ ., dataset_bake, Hess = TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
2: In polr(difficultyf ~ ., appTrain3_bake, Hess = TRUE) :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs

(this still produces a model though)

predict(polr_mod, dataset_test_bake)
Error in X %*% object$coefficients : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: If the `MASS::polr` call does not work a wrapper around polr function will not work either. This is a data dependent error and without seeing the data I am afraid no one can offer a better solution then to expand on the error.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what in the data might be causing the error? Anything to look for?

Comment: This is a useful post on the matter https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166566/multicollinearity-problems-with-polr-function-in-the-mass-package-for-ordinal

Comment: You might want to use: https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#lindep and https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#corr as `preProcess`. In otehr words recipes: https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/reference/step_lincomb.html, https://tidymodels.github.io/recipes/reference/index.html after you create a model matrix.

Comment: So, nothing found multicollinearity, except `findLinearCombos` which found collinearity between two variables that definitely do not correlate. I tried eliminating one and then both just to be sure and unfortunately still got the error.